# FastAPI Application in Docker Compose Unable to Connect to Redis Service

Tags: docker-compose, redis, containers, fastapi

When I start a standalone Redis container and connect using `localhost:6379`, everything works perfectly well

I'm attempting to run my FastAPI application and Redis service using Docker Compose. I'm using the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis_db:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: my-redis
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
    expose:
      - 6379
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  app:
    image: myapp
    container_name: meow_chat
    ports:
    - "1314:1314"
    depends_on:
      - redis_db
```

My redis connect code

```
from redis import asyncio as aioredis

redis_pool = None

async def init_redis_pool():
    global redis_pool
    redis_pool = aioredis.ConnectionPool.from_url('redis://redis_db:6379')
```

When attempting to run my services, my FastAPI application throws the following error:

```
 redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error connecting to localhost:6379. Multiple exceptions: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 6379), [Errno 99] Address not available.
```

In my FastAPI application, I've changed the Redis connection string from `localhost:6379` to `redis://redis_db:6379`. However, the issue persists. I've verified that I've updated the connection string in the application code and rebuilt the Docker image.

Inside the app container, I can successfully ping the redis_db service using the ping redis_db command. This seems to indicate that the network connection is fine.

I'm wondering what I might be missing, or what I need to do to resolve this issue.

Here are some things I've tried:

- Rebuilding my Docker image to ensure all changes have been applied.
- Verifying that my FastAPI application correctly reads the connection string from environment variables or configuration files.
- Implementing a mechanism in my "app" service that checks the availability of the "redis" service at startup, or waits a bit before attempting to connect.
  I welcome any possible suggestions or solutions, thank you!

Comment: You say you've verified that fastapi reads the connection string for the environment, but you have hardcoded the URL in your example - is this actually hardcoded in the app, are you sure this is the actual function being called? (also `aioredis` currently suggests using just `aioredis.from_url`: https://aioredis.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0.1/migration/#connecting-to-redis)

Comment: If you've changed your Python code, are you sure you've rebuilt the docker container? Try running `docker compose up --build`

Comment: @M.O.  Yes, I have rebuilt the Docker container. I just ran `docker compose up --build` and got the same result. My service is still attempting to connect to `localhost:6379`.

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes, this is indeed the hardcoded part in the application. The provided code is the actual code that I'm calling.